# Meaning of Harmonic oscilator correlation function In Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, harmonic-oscillator, correlation-functions

What is the **physical interpretation** of the quantity $$\xi(t)=\langle 0|x(t)x(0)|0\rangle=\frac{\hbar}{2m\omega}e^{-i\omega t}$$ where $|0\rangle$ is the ground state of the harmonic oscillator? I know it is some kind of correlation function but no being able to interpret it physically. If I could interpret the states $x(0)|0⟩$ and $x(t)|0⟩$ the rest should follow.

Comment: It should be completely evident from the definition of [statistical correlation functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_function) what two quantities are being correlated here. What's that *actual* question you want to ask?

Comment: Interpret? Qua Heisenberg operators, you resolve them into creation and annihilation operators. You chuck the annihilation operators annihilating the vacuum, and get $x(0)|0\rangle \sim |1\rangle$ and $x(t)|0\rangle \sim \exp(i\omega t) |1\rangle$, up to a factor. What, exaclty, are you up to???

Comment: I am mostly puzzled, and impatient to understand. Why is the time-autocorrelation function of one excited state of the oscillator significant? What's your point?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Well. In Sakurai's book, this appears as an exercise and I thought there might be some significance. That's all.

Comment: It's an exercise to ensure the student understands the notation enough to work out by inspection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is rather interesting and has never been clarified in textbooks. It could be used for didactical aims to explain the Dyson-Schwinger set of equations in an introductory course of quantum mechanics.

That expectation value $\langle x(t)x(0)\rangle$ represents the Green function of the corresponding classical equation for the harmonic oscillator. This can be understood using the technique devised by Carl M. Bender, Kimball A. Milton and Van M. Savage [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9907045). So, let us consider the quantum theory of a harmonic oscillator having action
$$
 S = \int dt\left[\frac{1}{2}m(\dot x(t))^2-\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2(x(t))^2+j(t)x(t)\right]
$$
where we have introduced a source $j(t)$ that is a c-number. Varying the action, one gets the equation of motion
$$
   m\ddot x(t)+m\omega^2x(t)=j(t).
$$
Now, using the technique of Bender at al., we take the expectation value of this equation on the ground state obtaining
$$
    m\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\langle x(t)\rangle+m\omega^2\langle x(t)\rangle = j(t).
$$
We divide this by the partition function $Z[j]=\langle 0|0\rangle$ obtaining
$$
   m\frac{d^2}{dt^2}G_1^j(t)+m\omega^2 G_1^j(t)=Z^{-1}[j]j(t)
$$
that is the one-point function of the harmonic oscillator. For $j(t)=0$ we recover the known classical equation of motion for $G_1^0(t)$. We have used the definition of correlation functions as
$$
    G_n^j=\frac{\delta^n}{\delta j(t_1)\delta j(t_2)\ldots\delta j(t_n)}\ln Z[j]
$$
and we set $j=0$ at the end of the computation. Now, we take the functional derivative with respect to $j(t)$ obtaining the equation for the two-point function. It is easy to see that, deriving the equation for $G_1^j(t)$ yields immediately
$$
   m\frac{d^2}{dt^2}G_2^j(t,t')+m\omega^2G_2^j(t,t')=-Z^{-1}[j]G_1^j(t)j(t)+Z^{-1}[j]\delta(t-t')
$$
and so, for $j=0$,
$$
   m\frac{d^2}{dt^2}G_2^0(t,t')+m\omega^2G_2^0(t,t')=\delta(t-t')
$$
where we have reabsorbed the factor $Z^{-1}[0]$ multiplying the delta with a redefinition of $G_2^0(t,t')$. We see that the case $\langle x(t)x(0)\rangle$ represents the solution for $t>0$ of this equation when $t'=0$. So, it propagates the motion of a particle under an elastic force in time when an external source is present. In quantum mechanics, it arises from the deviation of the average path that is that of a classical particle. We note that higher order correlation functions are just trivial for this case as it should be expected. It would be more interesting for a cubic potential as in the paper of Bender et al.

Comment: I very much fear (I know) you have misconnected the interpretation of symbols in a drastic way. Even if you did produce the full propagator in your overkill discussion, a pointless challenge, for the oscillator the propagator is the [Mehler kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator#Basic_examples:_propagator_of_free_particle_and_harmonic_oscillator) and not your or the OP's expression. The OP is just seeing a trivial matrix element , just the first excited state component of the full propagator, $\sum_n |n\rangle e^{-iE_n t/\hbar} \langle n|$, one out of an infinity.

Comment: @CosmasZachos The point is that that matrix element is the part of the propagator for $t>t'$. It is also silly to downvote a correct argument. I would rely on the OP judgement. Of course, I properly stated at the start of the post that the reason to present it was just educational and this was also the main motivation.

Comment: So, in what way does anyone understand $\langle 0 |a e^{-i\omega t} a^\dagger |0\rangle $ better by embedding it into a structure that is not even worked out for the oscillator here, and confusing it with $|x\rangle$ states?

Comment: What appears rather clear is your misunderstanding of the question by the OP.

Comment: I would like to add the content of Sakurai's problem. Please, take the book on page 146, problem 15. This refers to the position operator. So, please remove the downvote because you are plain wrong.

Comment: I only have the modern version, Sakurai and Napolitano,  and the OP's problem appears to be their 2.16. *x* is, indeed,  a Heisenberg operator!!   You are asking me to abandon common sense deferring to  mystical external authority. Besides, if you are fishing for input on ***who***  downvoted, it is not working. I'm trying to help you understand the point, which, evidently is not your point, too.

Comment: @CosmasZachos No, sorry. It is not me talking about science and asking for an imaginary authority. I have understood the OP's request in a deeper way that agreed with the Sakurai's book. It seemed to me really funny this approach I have proposed to understand the physical meaning but just for educational aims. Indeed, doing Dyson-Schwinger with the harmonic oscillator is like to shot to a fly with a cannon.

Comment: We are still miscommunicating. The point that *x* is a Heisenberg operator is the point I've been making. One *never* considers its eigenvalues here. Sakurai & N are working in Fock space, and *not* eigenstates of *x*. How do I get this across?

Comment: @CosmasZachos just let me think on this.

Comment: I think we can easily fix this matter. If you have $C(t)=\langle x(t)x(0)\rangle$ then $G_2^0(t,0)=\theta(t)C(t)+\theta(-t)C^*(t)$. Finally, you can express $x$ using $a^\dagger,\ a$ as usual that gives $C(t)$ working in Fock space. $C(t)$ is that written by the OP anyway. The physical meaning is subtle but is always the same.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment you ask:

> How do you interpret the states $x(0)|0⟩$ and $x(t)|0⟩$?

Answer: You don't. You should *not* read the correlation function as the overlap of these two states. Instead, you should view it as the expectation value of the (Heisenberg) operator $x(t)x(0)$ with respect to the state $\lvert 0 \rangle$. Then it becomes clearly a measure of statistical correlation in the usual sense: Both $x(0)$ and $x(t)$ may be viewed as random variables, and the expectation values of both individually are zero, so $\langle x(t)x(0)\rangle$ is the [covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance) of these two variables. If you divide by the standard deviations you obtain [Pearson's correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient).

Comment: These are just mathematical jargons. But I wanted a physical interpretation of the correlation function. @ACuriousMind

Comment: @SRS You asked "what is it the correlation between?" and the answer is "between the random variables $x(0)$ and $x(t)$". If you want to know what the *meaning* of correlations is you should've asked a different question (and possibly at [stats.SE] and not here).

Comment: Edited. @ACuriousMind